# How can I achieve this TOC layout?

Tags: table-of-contents, layout

I'm working on a software for which I need to write up a LaTeX template. I've been able to glue together the rest of the template somehow since I'm a beginner. But I'm facing huge difficulty in getting the **Table of Contents** right. I personally like the layout of the TOC used in *G.F. Simmon*'s book on *Differential Equations* and was hoping that I could implement it in my template.

[image: The TOC Layout]

I don't care about the image before the title. Also, the dark background is actually the job of my reader, Okular, so I need the background to be white as usual.

Thanks in advance.

> I know this might sound lazy of me to just ask up how to achieve this, but I've actually invested a couple of days on this. I came to know about packages, `tocloft` etc, tried reading the documentation too, but it's just taking too much time and I can't force myself to be spending any more time on this. My current state is that I can't go out exploring the docs and stuff, but will be able to understand and implement the layout if I have a starting point at least.

Comment: Which class are you using?

Comment: I'm currently using the `book` class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is this close to what you want?

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
%
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\raggedleft \sffamily \MakeUppercase{Table of Contents}}
%
%
\titlecontents{chapter}[-7em]{\sffamily \bfseries \addvspace{5ex}}%
{\MakeUppercase \chaptername{} {\huge \thecontentslabel} \quad \Large \MakeUppercase}%
{}%
{\hfill \Large \contentspage}%
[\addvspace{1ex}]%
%
%
\titlecontents{section}[1em]{}%
{\thecontentslabel \quad}%
{}%
{\hfill \contentspage}%
%
%
\titlecontents{subsection}[3.2em]{}%
{\thecontentslabel \quad}%
{}%
{\hfill \contentspage}%
%
%
\usepackage{blindtext}
%
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
%
\blinddocument
\blinddocument
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe chapter titles in toc in mdseries would look better than bold.

Comment: Thanks for your help. This is exactly what I needed. I'll keep it in mind to credit you once the software's done.

Comment: @hesham Just a doubt. Why have you commented out the empty lines?

Comment: No special reason. I just wanted to improve the readability of the code. You can delete the commented lines and still obtain the same results.